# Search all smart contracts

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I would like to search the code (binary grep) of all deployed contracts. The goal is to search for vulnerabilities and other research.

How can I do this with geth, Parity or the like? And is this feasible, like will it take years to do a search?

Comment: Do you mean search in bytecode or in Solidity code?

Comment: Search all bytecode

Answer (score 9):

You can query contract bytecode in this public BigQuery dataset https://medium.com/@medvedev1088/more-blockchain-analysis-on-bigquery-92a863137f01

---

*Previous answer*

It's not possible via JSON RPC or web3 API. Scanning the Patricia trie wouldn't work either because the [addresses are hashed there](http://Getting%20complete%20state%20of%20a%20smart%20contract).

To list all contracts you'd need to do:

- list all transactions where `to` address is `0x0` - these are contract-creating transactions
- execute all transactions and intercept `CREATE` opcodes - opcode for creating a contact

  - alternatively [transaction traces](http://Getting%20complete%20state%20of%20a%20smart%20contract) can be inspected

For each address collected above then

- call [`eth_getCode`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getcode) or the corresponding web3 API to get the bytecode.

---

An alternative is to try to scrape contract code from Etherscan. I've scraped some  using this Scrapy script https://github.com/medvedev1088/ethereum-scraper

About 7k contracts with bytecode and Solidity code can be found here http://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmU7pxFykAwemy8vGcAp78pUnHuye4gjjCiBsDsqV1raeF 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YWMUhXd97OEC24gyG_kKvo6xfwZ3K8xB

Answer (score 0):

For Solidity (verified) code, Etherscan launched a [search tool](https://info.etherscan.com/using-smart-contract-search-tool/).